# How are instance variables used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say in one controller for comments, I have

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end
```

In what views can I access `@comment`?

Say for example, in my questions controller under show, I have a link to `form_for` for comments. Can I access @comment there? Or can I only access it at a page create for comments?

Comment: In any views which are being rendered by current action.

Comment: @Allerin You should rather add this as an answer.

Comment: How do I know which views are being rendered by the current action?

Comment: @google1254 By reading the action and understanding how Rails renders a view called `app/views/<controller name>/<action name>` by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to ask "in which views". There is only one view, the view that is rendered by the action. This defaults to a view matching the action name, located in `app/views/<controller name>`.

You cannot access it in any other view rendered by any other action, only the view rendered by *this* action. *This action must execute* for `@comment` to be set.

Comment: Oh it makes sense to ask it. However it shows a clear lack of research effort. This stuff is covered in the first ten minutes of any basic Rails tutorial.

Comment: Figured it out, the tutorials weren't too clear to me at first despite reading them.